# Enable proguard crashs when run app (Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")

Tags: android, proguard, androidx

I have migrated my app to AndroidX. Everything works normally if I disable proguard. If I enable proguard, the app can build successfully but crashed when I open app.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
>           at com.app.example.utils.da.a(Unknown Source:15)
>           at com.app.exampler.utils.da.b(Unknown Source:10)
>           at com.app.example.utils.da.a(Unknown Source:9)
>           at com.app.example.base.MyApplication.onCreate(Unknown Source:2)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1162)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6636)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:268) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1995) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7539) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958) 
>   2019-07-25 07:14:46.903 1437-1437/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate
>   appComponentFactory
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[]

I tried some solution below but they didn't help.

**proguard-rules.pro**

> -keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; }

**manifest.xml**

> tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
>   android:appComponentFactory="whatevestring"

Anyone got the same issue like me? And how you resolve it? Thank you.

Comment: Use         android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue after enabling proguard. In my case the issue got resolved by cleaning the project. Try to run the app after cleaning.

Android Studio -> Build -> Clean Project

No need to add additional proguard rule or anything additional in manifest file.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks Mayank! This really works. Even adding proGuard rules was not working for me.